# Bandwidth required for orthogonal and antipodal signals

Tags: signal-analysis

What is the bandwidth required to transmit baseband modulated signals like an antipodal and orthogonal signals?

Comment: What does the modulation theorem: $$\mathcal F[x(t)]cos(2\pi f_c t)] = \left.\left.\frac{1}{2}\right[(X(f-f_c) + X(f+f_c)\right]$$ suggest to you when $x(t)$ is the baseband modulated signal of bandwidth $B$ Hz and $f_c \gg B$? Draw a sketch of $X(f)$ (the details of the spectrum are irrelevant except for the limitation that $X(f) = 0$ for $|f| > B$) and the spectrum of the modulated signal on the same axes to help you think about the matter.

Comment: I'm not sure what you actually mean by "baseband modulated signals". What kind of modulation scheme do you use?

Comment: In what sense? I am using PCM to get digital signals